# Unable to see confirmation message via LocationUtil RequestScopedInfoMessage

Tags: guidewire, gosu

am New to Guidewire:

Currently not getting warning message on toggling checkbox; is it some restriction or am I missing  some setting/property?;

which is prerequisite for this confirmation message before pressing ok  or blocking this message.

Please share.

It is Guidewire 8.28.0

```
LocationUtil.addRequestScopedInfoMessage(displaykey.Web.Policy.DuplicateMsgSent)
```

Comment: Are you trying to throw the Info message from PCF Element or from any Gosu class .. ?

Comment: This code is written in an Enhancement

Comment: are you want to see the confirmation message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand your requirement correctly, On clicking on "OK" button, some logic should be executed to find if the message is duplicate and then a Confirm message popup is expected in Screen. If my understanding is correct then i think you can not achieve this as you expect.

You need to know that, the "Confirm message popup" will trigger immediately as soon as you click the "OK" button and then your code logic to find duplicate is executed.

The code written in enhancement will only throw the info or warning or error like string messages to the UI screen.

As far as i know, In this case you can make use of any points below,

1. See if you can use the "addRequestScopedWarningMessage" which will show as a warning message in UI.
2. Write the duplicate finding logic in the "post on change" property based on the value in UI fields. We can then throw the "addRequestScopedWarningMessage" or "addRequestScopedInfoMessage" in UI before clicking the "OK" button.

I hope its helps you.

Comment: Yes, found by myself after lot of debugging; postOnChange was the property needed to trigger/call function/code above in Enhancement on checkbox toggle. You was in right direction.

Answer (score -1):

You might forget to give `showConfirmMessage=true` and call that method at `confirmMessage` property.

[image]

Comment: the showConfirmationMessage is already true; and this method is called when pressing "ok" on toolbar. Just before currentLocation.commit() this line of code is written to confirm further processing.